add view button to existing files in dropzone js
I want to add a view button to preview existing files( mockfile ) . For example, when I want to modify a form, the files are displayed in the dropzone, so I want to preview them. this is my code:
var myDropzone2 = new Dropzone("#dataListUpload_modif", {
    url: "../app/controler/update_contact.php ",
    parallelUploads: 3,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    dictRemoveFile: 'Supprimer le fichier',
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    autoQueue:true,
    clickable: true,
    removedfile: function (file) {

        // only show swal dialog if file is being removed manually
    swal({
      title: "Suppression?",
      text: "Etes vous sûr de vouloir supprimer ce fichier?",
      icon: "warning",
      buttons: true,
      dangerMode: true,
    })
    .then((willDelete) => {
      if (willDelete) {
        console.log(file);
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "../app/controler/deleteDoc.php",
          data: {
            'name': file.name
            
          },
          cache: false,
          success: function (result) {
            file.previewElement.remove();
          }
        });
      }
    });

},
init: function() {
   
  
    console.log('test');
    var mocks  = <?php echo json_encode($documents);  ?>;
    for (var i = 0; i < mocks.length; i++) {
    var mock = mocks[i];
    var mockFile = {
        name: mocks[i].titre,
        size: mocks[i].taille,
        id: mocks[i].id,
        url: mocks[i].chemin
    };
    console.log(mockFile);
    var viewButton = Dropzone.createElement("<div class='column'><span class='btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right view'>view</span></div>");
   // this.files.push(mockFile);
    this.emit('addedfile', mockFile, mock.chemin);
    this.createThumbnailFromUrl(mockFile, mock.chemin);
    this.emit('complete', mockFile);
}

I tried to preview files existing on the server. For example, when I want to modify a form, the files are displayed in the dropzone, so I want to preview them.
